# Chrome and IE return different SHA hashes

Tags: javascript, c#, google-chrome, internet-explorer, asp.net-web-api2

I have written a website that utilizes a SHA-256 hash to validate a user's password. This is a relatively unsecure setup to start with, as most users will have the same username/password. To try and protect it at least a little bit, I do the following:

1. The client requests a new salt from the server
2. The client hashes the password with this salt
3. The client sends the hashed password with the salt back to the server
4. The server hashes the actual password and compares the two

Here is my code:

**C#**

```
//Just for testing!
private static Dictionary<string, string> users = new Dictionary<string, string>() { { "User", "Password" } };

[HttpGet]
public HttpResponseMessage GetSalt()
{
   RNGCryptoServiceProvider secureRNG = new RNGCryptoServiceProvider();
   byte[] saltData = new byte[64];

   secureRNG.GetBytes(saltData);

   HttpResponseMessage response = new HttpResponseMessage();
   response.Content = new StringContent(System.Text.Encoding.Unicode.GetString(saltData), System.Text.Encoding.Unicode);
   return response;
}

[HttpGet]
public bool ValidateUser(string userName, string hashedPassword, string salt)
{
   SHA256Managed hash = new SHA256Managed();         
   if (users.ContainsKey(userName))
   {
       string fullPassword = salt + users[userName];
       byte[] correctHash = hash.ComputeHash(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(fullPassword));

       if (hashedPassword.ToUpper() == BitConverter.ToString(correctHash).Replace("-",""))
       {
           return true;
       }
   }
   return false;
}
```

**Javascript**

```
$scope.login = function () {
    $http.get('api/Login').success(function (salt) {
        //Hash the password with the salt and validate
        var hashedPassword = sjcl.hash.sha256.hash(salt.toString().concat($scope.password));
        var hashString = sjcl.codec.hex.fromBits(hashedPassword);

        $http.get('api/Login?userName=' + $scope.userName + '&hashedPassword=' + hashString + '&salt=' + salt).success(function (validated) {
            $scope.loggedIn = validated;
        });
    });
```

This code works fine on Google Chrome, but not on Internet Explorer 11. The problem (as seen in the debugger) is that the hash generated by the javascript is different than that generated by C#.

I *suspect* this has something to do with character encoding, but haven't found much on the web to prove/disprove this theory (or help with the problem in general). If there is a better way to accomplish this problem, I'm happy to hear about it but would like understanding as to the cause of the original error as well.

**Why are the hashes different, and what can I do to fix it?**

Comment: What's "sjcl" ? I'd make sure the JS and C# hashers produce the same output, through a massive, random-string based comparison run (i.e. generate 1 million random strings, hash them on both sides, compare results). To keep things deterministic (so results are significant) I'd use no salt at all for this test run.

Comment: @Alex sjcl is the Stanford Javascript Crypto library. Since it works fine with Chrome, are you suggesting running Chrome against C#, IE against C# or both (without the salt as suggested)?

Comment: All of the above: if Chrome always works and IE never does, you can confirm it's a browser issue. Now, if one of them *sometimes* works...

Comment: 1) Start with testing on more browsers to make sure it is a browser issue. Opera and Firefox springs to mind. For all we know you might have a long forgotten plugin in one of them, or NSA spy ware. 2) You mention that there is IE/Chrome differences; but you also mention that there is difference between hash result in javascript and c#.  3) Finally you suspect character encoding which imho looks like a possible explanation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IE does **not** like Unicode characters in the query string. It also doesn't like some "special" characters that are ASCII. Even though it accepts them correctly, and performs the hash correctly, when you run this code, the salt is "???????" when coming from IE, and the correct string when coming from Chrome.

The simple fix is to just limit the character set of the salt to upper-case, lower-case, and numbers. Using this method, both browsers give the correct hash.